# Julia speed of execution

Tags: julia

I'm benchmarking Julia execution speed. I executed `@time [i^2 for i in 1:1000]` on Julia prompt, which resulted in something of the order of 20 ms. This seems strange, since my computer is modern with an i7 processor (I am using Linux Ubuntu).

Another strange thing is that when I execute the same command on a range of `1:10` the execution time is 15 ms.

There must be something trivial that I am missing here?

Answer (score 9):

Several things, see [performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/):

1. Don't benchmark in global scope.
2. Don't measure the first execution of something like this.
3. Use [BenchmarkTools](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl).

Julia is a JIT-compiled language, so the first time you measure things, you're measuring compilation time. This is a small fixed overhead, so for anything that takes a substantial time, it's negligible, but for short-running code like this, it's almost all of the time. Non-constant global variables force the compiler to assume almost nothing about types, which tends to poison all of your performance. This is fine in some circumstances, but most of the time, you a) should write code so that the inputs are explicit parameters to functions, rather than implicit parameters coming from some globals, and b) shouldn't write code that uses mutable global state.

Comment: I did not measure the first execution. The 20ms is the execution time in the 2nd execution and on. The same benchmark was claimed in a Julia tutorials to take less than 1ms.

Comment: Ok I got it right now. It seems that when I run this in the command prompt, it compiles every time. So, I defined this code in a function inside an *.il file and called the function. Indeed, after from the second time it took less than 1 ms on a 1:100000 list. Thanks!

Comment: @NSL - Benchmarking in the global space is a common trap for many new users, always benchmark a function excluding the first run because it includes compile time. That said, even if you run this comprehension list in the REPL with return type annotation, `@time (Int64)[i^2 for i in 1:1000];`, this runs in about `4μ sec`. Refer to [this JuliaCon 2016 talk](https://youtu.be/szE4txAD8mk) for more details on many similar tricks for writing good Julia code.