# Julia Array taking huge memory

Tags: julia

Created an 10X10 random array using the function rand(a,b). The first time, 957KB memory was used but in the second time only 1KB memory was used. Why is this happening?

Here is reference screenshot:

[image: see the screenshot]

Comment: First time `@time` includes compile time and memory usage.

Comment: Meta-comment: 1. Best to avoid screenshots to allow cut-and-paste. 2. This question is surely a duplicate, as it tricks everyone the first time ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Julia speed of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263741/julia-speed-of-execution)

Comment: and what is that ungodly-looking terminal? surely this isn't ... (gasp) ... Windows?